# How to access a select option observable for selected value from another view model?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have two view models, one contained an `observable` which receives the selectedValue from the `select option`.

How do I access the selected value, in this case, the `selecteArtist()` from another view model? I need to pass this as an argument in ViewModelB each time the value is changed.

*ViewModel A:*

```
function ViewModelA(){

    var self = this;

    // Access this from outside
    self.selectedArtist = ko.observable();

    var data = [{
        "ArtistId": "1",
        "LastName": "Secada",
        "FirstName": "Jon"
    },

    {
       "ArtistId": "2",
       "LastName": "Dion",
       "FirstName": "Celine"

    }];


    self.artists = ko.computed(function () {

       return ko.utils.arrayMap(data,

               function (artist) {

                    return {
                        fullName: artist.FirstName + ' ' + artist.LastName,
                        value: artist.ArtistId
           }

         });
    });
}
```

*ViewModel B*:

```
function ViewModelB(){
    var self = this;

    // Something like this:
    var viewModelA = new ViewModelA();

    self.selArtist = ko.observable(viewModelA.selectedArtist().value);

}
```

*I attempted to do something like this:*

```
    self.selArtist = ko.computed(function () {

        if(self.selectedArtist()){
            return self.selectedArtist().ArtistId;
        }
    });
```

*Then access like this:*

```
    var viewModelA = new ViewModelA();
    viewModelA.selArtist();
```

Result: `undefined:`

*Update:*

Based on comments below I change the code slightly but I still cannot access selected value from viewModelA.

For example this works:

```
   self.firstName = ko.observable('Bob');
   self.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');

   self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
    });
```

*Call like this:*

```
var viewModelB = function(vma){
    var self = this;

    // Alert for example:
    alert(vma.fullName());
};

var viewModelMain = (function(){
    var self = this;
    self.viewModelA =  new viewModelA();
    self.viewModelB = new viewModelB(self.viewModelA);
})();
```

If I attempt to call the `self.selectedArtist().value` it does not work as stated above.

Comment: It looks like you're creating a new ViewModelA and then getting it's selected artist. Are you expecting this brand new view model to have a selected artist at this point?

Comment: Yes. I need to create multiple viewmodels and to access the selected value from viewmodel A.

Comment: You should probably pass the parent view model's observable down to the child to use. That way you have one observable being used by two view models. You could also create a computed in the parent view model with a dependency on the child's observable.

Comment: not clear- what do you want to do? attach details and meanning

Comment: If you have viewmodel A, and it has a "selectedItem" property, and you make it a cild of viewmodel B - why should viewmodel B have the same "selectedItem" property as well? It's viewmodel A's job to keep track of what's selected, that's none of viewmodel B's business. You don't explain what you are actually trying to *do* here. (see "[What's the XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)").

Comment: In a nutshell: I am attempting to breakup a large view model. And in doing so I needed to know if I could move  codes that are dependent on the selected value of a property in View Model A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE: Working Solution:***

*What were you trying to do?*

I needed to break up a view model into smaller functional parts so that each major functionality is compartmentalized into it's own function (view model).

*What problems did you encountered?*

The application contained a `Select Option Binding` and I needed to access the Selected Value from another view model so that I can use the value as argument to perform additional bindings using a different view model.

However, I could not access the `Selected Value`, and when I finally solved the problem, another problem arose, this time the `Select Options Binding` will not work if there were any dependent binding before it.

Because I was using the Selected Value as argument, if any dependent binding using the argument was placed above the select option HTML, the code did not work. The select option had to come first:

*Solution:*

HTML:

```
   <!-- Binding with View Model B --> 
    <div id="artist-detail" data-bind="with: ArtistBio()[0]">
    <p data-bind="text: ArtistId"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: Bio"></p>
    </div>

   <!-- Binding with View Model A -->
    <div id="artist-list">
        <select data-bind="options: Artists, 
    optionsText: 'FullName', value: SelectedArtist"></select>
    </div>
```

*View Model A:*

```
 function ViewModelA(){

     var self = this;

     self.SelectedArtist = ko.observable();

     var artistList = [{
         "ArtistId": "1",
         "LastName": "Secada",
         "FirstName": "Jon"
     },

         {
             "ArtistId": "2",
             "LastName": "Dion",
             "FirstName": "Celine"

         }];


     self.Artists = ko.computed(function () {
         return ko.utils.arrayMap(artistList,

       function (artist) {

          return {

         FullName: artist.FirstName + ' ' + artist.LastName,
            value: artist.ArtistId
      }
        });
     });
 }
```

*View Model B:*

```
 function ViewModelB(vma){

     var self = this;

     var artistDetail = [{
         "ArtistId": "1",
         "Bio": "Jon Secada is a Cuban American singer and songwriter. " +
         "Secada was born in Havana, Cuba, and raised in Hialeah, Florida. " +
         "He has won two Grammy Awards and sold 20 million albums since his " +
         "English-language debut album in 1992"
     },

         {
             "ArtistId": "2",
             "Bio": "Céline Marie Claudette Dion, CC OQ ChLD is a Canadian " +
             "singer, songwriter, businesswoman and occasional actress."
         }];

     self.ArtistBio = ko.computed(function () {
         if(vma.SelectedArtist()){
             return ko.utils.arrayFilter(artistDetail, function (item) {

                 // Access the selected value here and return matching actist
                 return item.ArtistId === vma.SelectedArtist().value;
             });
         }
     });
 }
```

*Perform Binding of both View Models:*

```
 var viewModelA = new ViewModelA();
 var viewModelB = new ViewModelB(viewModelA);

 ko.applyBindings(viewModelA, document.getElementById('artist-list'));
 ko.applyBindings(viewModelB, document.getElementById('artist-detail'));
```

With this code, it does not matter where I place the select list, because I am calling and binding to View Model A first.

This is my fourth week of learning `KnockoutJS` and so please feel free to improve the answer.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7kx81kwh/1/) with a working example:

Answer (score 0):

I've asked [a similar question on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62735/10034). Basically, there are three options:

1. Pass the parent to the child and place logic in the child view model;
2. Let the parent handle everything about the children as well;
3. Create a managing service / object that handles these things.

I've found the third option not to play well with Knockout, but note that this is mostly opinion.

I've found the second option to be useful when the child class is very small and/or a leaf node in your view model tree.

I've found that I've usually ended up using the first option. With the code you've given us to go on this makes the most sense for you as well. E.g.:

```
function ViewModelB(parent){
    var self = this;

    self.selArtist = ko.computed(function () {
        if(!!parent.selectedArtist()){
            return parent.selectedArtist().id;
        }
        return undefined;
    });
}

function ArtistVm(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = data.ArtistId;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(data.LastName);
    self.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return self.firstName() + ' ' + self.lastName();
    });
}

function ViewModelA(){
    var self = this;

    self.selectedArtist = ko.observable(null);    

    self.artists = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data,
        function (artist) {
            return new ArtistVm(artist);
        });
    });

    self.viewModelB = ko.observable(new ViewModelB(self));
}
```